# Accessibility - lang html tag not being recongnised

Tags: accessibility

Have been running some accessibility checkers our website and they seem to indicate lang tag is empty.
Initially I thought the problem was caused because language was setup to be `en-US`.  So I changed it to `en-UK`
Here is the code on `header.php`

```
   <!DOCTYPE html /><!--[if lt IE 7]>
   <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" <?php    language_attributes(); ?>><![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
   <![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9" <?php language_attributes(); ?>><![endif]-->
   <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js" <?php language_attributes(); ?>><!--<![endif]-->
```

On wp-config.php I have set `define('WPLANG', 'en-GB');`.  Have also downloaded a localised version of Wordpress.  Created a languages subdirectory within wp-content and uploaded the `en_GB.mo` file onto it.

When I run this on the accessibility checker I am still getting an error saying lang tag is empty

http://wave.webaim.org/report#/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.warwickshire.gov.uk%2F

Could anybody point me in the right direction to fix this as it's being flagged up by other accessibility audits run on the site.
Many thanks.

Comment: you should run html checker first, mine reports that your document type has an extra illegal slash

Comment: I think your problem is not related with WordPress at all. Your HTML is wrong. For example, `<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en-GB"><!--<![endif]-->` should be `<!--[if gt IE 8]><html class="no-js" lang="en-GB"><![endif]-->`. As @MarkKaplun said, check your HTML. Voted for close the question as it is not WordPress specific.

Comment: Thank you! have run html checker. Removed illegal slash on `<!DOCTYPE html />`.  Will look further into HTML formatting.  using HTML5 Boilerplate version of Bootstrap. Will check nothing is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be two reasons, the first one is that you missed using `xml:lang` attribute, also this is not mandatory. Maybe, Wave do care about it?

```
<html xml:lang="en_US" lang="en_US">
```

The second one, is the way you define your `html` tag which can cause problem to the Webaim parser.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en-GB"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en-GB"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en-GB"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en-GB"><!--<![endif]-->
```

Note that the starting comment `<!-->` in the last line is not the same as `<!-- -->` See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#comments

I think that it's more some kind of parse error thing (I don't think Wabaim WAVE uses Webkit parser).

--- EDIT

After installating WAVE extension for Chrome, I can see that it does not return the error concerning the language of your page.

In fact, when you look closer at their online tool, they load a proxied version of your webpage, http://wave.webaim.org/data/getpage.php?reportkey=, with an `html` tag lacking of this attribute. So it is definitely a problem with the Wave parser.

So I suggest you to use the Chrome extension, which will be a better solution to pre-test your website as it does not modify your tag.

Comment: Been looking into this.  As per above we are using HTML5 Boilerplate which follows conditional IE formatting based on Paul Irish - see last paragraph - http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/
Lang tag is dynamically generated by Wordpress `<?php language_attributes(); ?>`.  Just to be sure I ran the actual Wordpress Codex url through Wave and it did not flag up a missing language tag - yet they use `lang="en`.
Sounds like there is  a bug in here somewhere but I cannot seem to narrow it down yet...

Comment: You are on the money @Adam.  It worked.  I can't vote your answer as I haven't got enough reputation.  Happy to accept it as the one the solved this particular problem.

Comment: Glad I could help. Come back when you can if you want to accept my answer. I also have tested with a C DOM parser your HTML and I can retrieve the html tag with no problem. So your code is definitely OK for me.

Comment: Thanks again!  This definitely seems to be a problem with Wave.  Have installed the Firefox toolbar and it is picking the lang tag no problem.  Will report it and submit this as evidence so they look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this problem even without the IE conditional comments in there. I have / had (depending on when you may read this) a website with just this start:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- etc -->
```

And it also pops up with the error. I sent in this bug report:

> WAVE feedback sent at 10:54 AM, October 11th, 2015
>
> URL: `http://wave.webaim.org/report#/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jeroenheijmans.nl`
>
> The URL in question (a wave report of my index page on www.jeroenheijmans.nl) reports a missing "lang" attribute on the "html" element. However, the element is clearly there (if you open the site on its own in a seperate tab and view the source you'll see this). I get this both with Chrome and Firefox latest version on Windows 8.1. I've also tried Chrome incognito mode.
>
> It does seem that if I choose "View Frame Source" on my page inside the WAVE tool that I get a source without the "lang" attribute. I might be experiencing the same issue as `https://stackoverflow.com/q/28692421/419956` where it's suggested that the problem is with the way WAVE loads the page under evaluation.

And received the following feedback:

> This is a known bug with WAVE that will be fixed in a release in the
>   very near future.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Jared Smith
>   WebAIM.org

In short, you're fine. You can try the workaround suggested in [the other answer by @Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28692755/419956), or just ignore the error safely.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this problem you have fix two tags for your tool to stop pointing accessibility error. You have to set both "lang" as well as "xml:lang" tag. One way to achieve this through pure Javascript is below. I am proposing this solution as it is independent of any platform.

```
(function() {
       document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].setAttribute('lang', 'en-US');
       document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].setAttribute('xml:lang','en-US');
})();
```

You may replace 'en' with language of your choice to correctly point the correct language in place